# Как в Unity считывать txt файл, не вписывая полный путь до него

Tags: c#, unity3d

C# Есть такая папка bin -> Debug -> файл.txt. Его путь не нужно вписывать полностью, а компилятор ищет сам в Debug. А в Unity как этот файл найти не вписывая полный путь, а только название txt файла.

Comment: Никак, компилятор ничего не ищет. Ваш файл лежит с вашим экзешником, поэтому **относительный** путь от программы до этого файла - это и есть название файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В юнити возможно открывать файлы не вписывая полный путь, если файл размещен в папке [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html). В таком случае можно открывать по относительному пути к StreamingAssets.

Для этого просто используй `Application.streamingAssetsPath + "твой относительный путь"`

важно иметь ввиду что содержимое папки StreamingAssets не пережимается и не оптимизируется под юнити так что сильно баловаться размещая там ресурсы нежелательно.